# Pre-empting NSOperation on one NSOperationQueue with NSOperation placed onto a separate NSOperationQueue?

Tags: objective-c, ios, concurrency

I have an application in which a long running process (> 1 min) is placed onto an NSOperationQueue (Queue A). The UI is fully-responsive while the Queue A operation runs, exactly as expected.

However, I have a different kind of operation the user can perform which runs on a completely separate NSOperationQueue (Queue B).

When a UI event triggers the placement of an operation on Queue B, it must wait until **after** the currently-executing operation on Queue A finishes. This occurs on an iPod Touch (MC544LL).

What I expected to see instead was that any operation placed onto Queue B would more or less begin immediately executing in parallel with the operation on Queue A. This is the behavior I see on the Simulator.

My question is two parts:

- Is the behavior I'm seeing on my device to be expected based on available documentation?
- Using NSOperation/NSOperationQueue, how do I pre-empt the currently running operation on Queue A with a new operation placed on Queue B?

Note: I can get exactly the behavior I'm after by using GCD queues for Queues A/B, so I know my device is capable of supporting what I'm trying to do. However, I really, really want to use NSOperationQueue because both operations need to be cancelable.

I have a simple test application:

[image]

The ViewController is:

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  QueueTest
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSOperationQueue *slowQueue;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSOperationQueue *fastQueue;

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        self.slowQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        self.fastQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"View loaded on thread %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
}

// Responds to "Slow Op Start" button
- (IBAction)slowOpStartPressed:(id)sender {
    NSBlockOperation *operation = [[NSBlockOperation alloc] init];

    [operation addExecutionBlock:^{
        [self workHard:600];
    }];

    [self.slowQueue addOperation:operation];
}

// Responds to "Fast Op Start" button
- (IBAction)fastOpStart:(id)sender {    
    NSBlockOperation *operation = [[NSBlockOperation alloc] init];

    [operation addExecutionBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"Fast operation on thread %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
    }];

    [self.fastQueue addOperation:operation];
}

-(void)workHard:(NSUInteger)iterations
{
    NSLog(@"SlowOperation start on thread %@", [NSThread currentThread]);

    NSDecimalNumber *result = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:@"0"];

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {        
        NSDecimalNumber *outer = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithUnsignedInteger:i];

        for (NSUInteger j = 0; j < iterations; j++) {
            NSDecimalNumber *inner = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithUnsignedInteger:j];
            NSDecimalNumber *product = [outer decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:inner];

            result = [result decimalNumberByAdding:product];
        }

        result = [result decimalNumberByAdding:outer];
    }

    NSLog(@"SlowOperation end");
}

@end
```

The output I see after first pressing the "Slow Op Start" button followed ~1 second later by pressing the "Fast Op Start" button is:

```
2012-11-28 07:41:13.051 QueueTest[12558:907] View loaded on thread <NSThread: 0x1d51ec30>{name = (null), num = 1}
2012-11-28 07:41:14.745 QueueTest[12558:1703] SlowOperation start on thread <NSThread: 0x1d55e5f0>{name = (null), num = 3}
2012-11-28 07:41:25.127 QueueTest[12558:1703] SlowOperation end
2012-11-28 07:41:25.913 QueueTest[12558:3907] Fast operation on thread <NSThread: 0x1e36d4c0>{name = (null), num = 4}
```

As you can see, the second operation does not begin executing until after the first operation finishes, despite the fact that these are two separate (and presumably independent) NSOperationQueues.

I have read the [Apple Concurrency Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW1), but find nothing describing this situation. I've also read two SO questions on related topics ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533955/two-simultaneous-background-tasks-using-nsoperationqueue), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018119/nsoperationqueue-not-reusing-thread-on-iphone)), but neither seems to get to the heart of the problem I'm seeing (pre-emption).

Other things I've tried:

- setting the queuePriority on each NSOperation
- setting the queuePriority on each NSOperation while placing both types of operations onto the same queue
- placing both operations onto the same queue

This question has undergone multiple edits, which may make certain comments/answers difficult to understand.

Comment: I see you cured the symptom while I was typing my answer :-) I suspect making the slow operation queue serial will do what you need if you require the operation management facilities of NSOperationQueue and can't use GCD.

Comment: @SimonLawrence, yes - our updates crossed paths :). Unfortunately, making the queue serial with [slowQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1] does not help. Is there another way?

Comment: In the code in your question, you're adding both operations to the same queue. Typo, or the cause of all your problems?

Comment: Typo left over from a variation I tried. Same behavior whether adding both ops to same or different queues.

Comment: Hi Rich, did you try my suggestion with an NSOperation subclass that runs the blocks without using GCD (see PseudoBlockOperation below)? That should do what you need for the long-running operations and is probably more appropriate than NSBlockOperation for these.

Comment: @SimonLawrence, thanks - but no dice. After talking to someone very knowledgeable on this subject, it looks like I'm out of options. I decided to stop fighting it. I did find a work around by simplifying the app to eliminate the need for pre-emption. Still, thanks for all the help on this.

Comment: Ah shame, sorry there wasn't a solution for you there.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem you are having is that both operation queues are executing their blocks on the underlying default priority dispatch queue. Consequently, if several slow operations are enqueued before the fast operations then perhaps you will see this behaviour.

Why not either set the NSOperationQueue instance for the slow operations so that it only executes one operation at any given time (i.e. set maxConcurrentOperationCount to one for this queue), or if your operations are all blocks then why not use GCD queues directly? e.g.

```
static dispatch_queue_t slowOpQueue = NULL;
static dispatch_queue_t fastOpQueue = NULL;

static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    slowOpQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Slow Ops Queue", NULL);
    fastOpQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Fast Ops Queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
});

for (NSUInteger slowOpIndex = 0; slowOpIndex < 5; slowOpIndex++) {
    dispatch_async(slowOpQueue, ^(void) {
        NSLog(@"* Starting slow op %d.", slowOpIndex);
        for (NSUInteger delayLoop = 0; delayLoop < 1000; delayLoop++) {
            putchar('.');
        }

        NSLog(@"* Ending slow op %d.", slowOpIndex);
    });
}

for (NSUInteger fastBlockIndex = 0; fastBlockIndex < 10; fastBlockIndex++) {
    dispatch_async(fastOpQueue, ^(void) {
        NSLog(@"Starting fast op %d.", fastBlockIndex);
        NSLog(@"Ending fast op %d.", fastBlockIndex);
    });
}
```

As far as using the NSOperationQueue as per your comments about needing the operation cancellation facilities etc. can you try:

```
- (void)loadSlowQueue
{
    [self.slowQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
    NSBlockOperation *operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"begin slow block 1");

        [self workHard:500];

        NSLog(@"end slow block 1");
    }];

    NSBlockOperation *operation2 = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"begin slow block 2");

        [self workHard:500];

        NSLog(@"end slow block 2");
    }];

    [self.slowQueue addOperation:operation];
    [self.slowQueue addOperation:operation2];
}
```

As I think the two blocks you add to the operation on the slow queue are being executed in parallel on the default queue and preventing your fast operations from being scheduled.

Edit:

If you're still finding the default GCD queue is choking, why not create an NSOperation subclass that executes blocks without using GCD at all for your slow operations, this will still give you the declarative convenience of not creating a separate subclass for each operation but use the threading model of a regular NSOperation. e.g.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef void (^BlockOperation)(NSOperation *containingOperation);

@interface PseudoBlockOperation : NSOperation

- (id)initWithBlock:(BlockOperation)block;
- (void)addBlock:(BlockOperation)block;

@end
```

And then for the implementation:

```
#import "PseudoBlockOperation.h"

@interface PseudoBlockOperation()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *blocks;

@end

@implementation PseudoBlockOperation

@synthesize blocks;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        blocks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
    }

    return self;
}

- (id)initWithBlock:(BlockOperation)block
{
    self = [self init];

    if (self) {
        [blocks addObject:[block copy]];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)main
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        for (BlockOperation block in blocks) {
            block(self);
        }
    }
}

- (void)addBlock:(BlockOperation)block
{
    [blocks addObject:[block copy]];
}

@end
```

Then in your code you can do something like:

```
PseudoBlockOperation *operation = [[PseudoBlockOperation alloc] init];
[operation addBlock:^(NSOperation *operation) {
    if (!operation.isCancelled) {
        NSLog(@"begin slow block 1");

        [self workHard:500];

        NSLog(@"end slow block 1");
    }
}];

[operation addBlock:^(NSOperation *operation) {
    if (!operation.isCancelled) {
        NSLog(@"begin slow block 2");

        [self workHard:500];

        NSLog(@"end slow block 2");
    }
}];

[self.slowQueue addOperation:operation];
```

Note that in this example any blocks that are added to the same operation will be executed sequentially rather than concurrently, to execute concurrently create one operation per block. This has the advantage over NSBlockOperation in that you can pass parameters into the block by changing the definition of BlockOperation - here I passed the containing operation, but you could pass whatever other context is required.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It's a step in the right direction, but as my edit (which crossed paths with your answer) indicates, I need to be able to cancel all operations. To my knowledge, this isn't possible with built-in GCD functionality.

Comment: I just noticed in your example, you're adding both slow blocks to the same NSOperation, which I believe means they will be exited in parallel on the GCD queue even though the NSOperationQueue is now set to serial, can you try adding the setMaxConcurrentOperations = 1 amending loadSlowQueue so that it adds an operation per block rather than putting them both in the same operation?

Comment: Adding [self.slowQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1] in viewDidLoad gave the same result as posted. The main problem remains: fastQueue is fully blocked until completion of the work on slowQueue. The two queues do not appear to be independent.

Comment: Did you also try not adding multiple blocks to the same operation for the slow queue though (see edit to the answer above)? If you add two blocks to an operation they can execute concurrently on the underlying GCD queue, whereas if you add one NSOperation per block on a serial NSOperationQueue then the operations and hence the blocks for that queue will execute sequentially, which should allow your other queue to run.

Comment: I just noticed you updated your answer with a new suggested loadSlowQueue method. It works in the sense of enabling fast operations to run between the two slow operations. However, the main problem is that no operations on fastQueue are being run until slow block 1 finishes execution. In my case this can take one minute or longer before I can get any fast operations to even start executing.

Comment: What hardware are you running on - you mentioned an iPod Touch, what CPU is it? The number of GCD blocks that can execute concurrently on the default queue is hardware dependent. If the code I posted above isn't solving it (i.e. splitting the slow queue operation into one operation per block) then it may be this limit you are hitting.